# FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create') not firing

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to make some functionality happen when the like button in a like box is clicked, however the function isn't firing (as well as two cross-domain errors appearing in the console, but I figure that's unrelated.)

Basically the code I'm using:

```
<div id="fb-root">
    <fb:like-box href="//www.facebook.com/MYPAGE" width="292" height="290"
     show_faces="true" stream="false" header="true"></fb:like-box>
</div>

<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'MYID',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
                alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
        });
    };

    (function(d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
</script>
```

MYPAGE and MYID are valid in the actual code, of course. 95% of the code is just copy/pasted, so I have no idea why it isn't working. If it's something obvious, then this should be easy points.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Edit- Oh and the HTML tag of course:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the likebox code _outside_ of the #fb-root element?